# Laravel reset password link

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have set up reset password method, so everything works fine so I receive link which address is:

> localhost/dashboard/password/reset/11bb83ff2815781dfebwef5060aa15706bad6a02a5d22328615bwef28fcfwefwef51a47

But after clicking on that link i am getting **404 Not Found**.

When i attached a port number after localhost it works.

> localhost:**8000**/dashboard/password/reset/11bb83ff2815781dfebwef5060aa15706bad6a02a5d22328615bwef28fcfwefwef51a47

Why is this happening ?

I am using **php -S localhost:8000 -t public** as server, but it was same when using artisan web server.

Comment: The URL is generated based on the `APP_URL` value in your `.env`, update it so that it contains `http://localhost:8000`.

Comment: @sam 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

Answer (score 3):

In your `config/app.php` you will have a `url` setting which will no doubt be set to just `localhost`. You should add your port there so Laravel is able to generate the correct URL.

Of course, the best way to do this in a development environment is to set an `APP_URL` in your `.env` file.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

Check out the `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword` class to see how Laravel generates the password reset email.

Comment: @jonathan, How can i modify reset password link without change in vendor file?